# Searching and displaying multiple results on the same page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to design a jsp page where by a user enters the name of a field ( say father's name) and enters a value. I want to search the database and return all those possible student name whose father's name matches to the one entered by the user.

---

Now, the problem is this that i want to return all the names of the student in a row wise manner ( pretty much like how google returns a set of values when we search for anything ) with a little description. I also want to display the result in the same page in which the user entered the values.

---

How should i use servlets to accomplish this. Just a little outlook of the code would be helpful ??

Answer (score 1):

> **I am trying to design a jsp page**

Here you need to have a simple page which can check `GET` request parameter such as:

```
http://www.example.com/?q=a+father+name&page=2&so-on-as-per-your-need
```

Now you will need *two* servlets:

1. First, `search` servlet that contains search options, like a field as you said.
2. Second, the `result`  servlet, having capacity to search an display result

> **I want to search the database**

Keep your *DAO* methods in separate class just to keep your business logic away from servlet or jsp.

I consider that you can search the database for your matching values, and as you said you want some description also you need to have that stored in database.

> **I also want to display the result in the same page**

You have `include` and `forward` options with JSP, you just have to take any of these options on the basis of parameter `q`, if it is `null` than `forward/include` the request on `search` servlet. If `q` has any value than `forward/include` the request to `result` servlet.

In this way you have only one view and two controllers for this.

Hope it helps.

Further Readings that may help you:

- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3541077/803285)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2010/07/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files.html)
- [Servlet and JSP Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html)